# Como capturar excepciones en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, excepciones

Estoy revisando las excepciones en oracle y tengo un problema, por ejemplo estoy realizando un sp que tiene una division por cero

```
procedure TEST(afectadas OUT NUMBER) 
IS
zero_div_e EXCEPTION 
divisor NUMBER;
division NUMBER;
BEGIN
  divisor := 0;
  IF (divisor = 0) THEN
    RAISE zero_div_e;
  ELSE 
    division := 10/DIVISOR;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN zero_div_e THEN
    inserto into tabla1 (division) values (null);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

END TEST;
```

El SP captura la excepcion de division por cero, o en este caso una excepcion personalizada **zero_div_e**, sin embargo al insertar la data en la tabla 1 en la columna division, esta saltando otro error que es que no se puede insertar null.

**Como puedo capturar esta segunda excepcion?, ya que no vuelve al bloque de excepcion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar anidación de bloques Begin/Exception/end para capturar explícitamente excepciones en puntos específicos de su código como en:

```
procedure TEST(afectadas OUT NUMBER) 
IS
  zero_div_e EXCEPTION 
  divisor NUMBER;
  division NUMBER;
BEGIN
  divisor := 0;
  IF (divisor = 0) THEN
    RAISE zero_div_e;
  ELSE 
    division := 10/DIVISOR;
  End if;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN zero_div_e THEN
      Begin
        insert into tabla1 (division) values (null);
      Exception
        when others then
             Dbms_Output.Put_Line('No se permite nulo');
      End;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END TEST;
```